# Pandas: remove duplicates deletes data when concatenate data frames with DateTime Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have 2 dataframes(some values are duplicated e.g. 2020-02-13):

```
>>> print(df1)
                   Val
Date                
2020-02-20         152.50
2020-02-19         152.53
2020-02-18         152.20
2020-02-13         152.28

>>> print(fd2)
                   Val
Date                
2018-02-20         141.40
2018-02-21         141.37
2018-02-22         141.17
2018-02-26         141.35
2018-02-27         140.69
...                   ...
2020-02-05         152.37
2020-02-06         152.20
2020-02-10         152.03
2020-02-11         151.19
2020-02-13         152.28
[298 rows x 1 columns]
```

both are indexed by Date (df1.set_index('Date')), and both dataframes dates were parsed (pd.to_datetime(df1.index)). Now I want to concate them both and remove duplicates (if any). I have tried

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2])
                   Val
Date                
2018-02-20         141.40
2018-02-21         141.37
2018-02-22         141.17
2018-02-26         141.35
2018-02-27         140.69
...                   ...
2020-02-13         152.28
2020-02-20         152.50
2020-02-19         152.53
2020-02-18         152.20
2020-02-13         152.28
[302 rows x 1 columns]
```

and I got new df with duplicates (2020-02-13). However when running

```
>>>pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates()
                   Val
Date                
2018-02-20         141.40
2018-02-21         141.37
2018-02-22         141.17
2018-02-26         141.35
2018-02-27         140.69
...                   ...
2020-02-06         152.20
2020-02-10         152.03
2020-02-11         151.19
2020-02-13         152.28
2020-02-20         152.50
[299 rows x 1 columns]
```

it remove the dumplicates, but also some values (2020-02-18 and 2020-02-19). Any idea why ? and what is the correct why to concatenate 2 dataframes indexed by date ?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-drop_duplicates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample:

```
print (df1)
               Val
Date              
2020-02-20  152.50
2020-02-19  152.53
2020-02-18  152.20
2020-02-13  152.28

print (df2)
               Val
Date              
2018-02-20  152.53
2018-02-21  141.37
2020-02-13  152.28
```

If join together:

```
print (pd.concat([df1, df2]))
               Val
Date              
2020-02-20  152.50
2020-02-19  152.53
2020-02-18  152.20
2020-02-13  152.28
2018-02-20  152.53
2018-02-21  141.37
2020-02-13  152.28
```

Your solution remove only duplicates by all columns, here `Val` column, index is not tested:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates()
print (df3)
               Val
Date              
2020-02-20  152.50
2020-02-19  152.53 <-dupe
2020-02-18  152.20
2020-02-13  152.28 <-dupe
2018-02-21  141.37
```

If convert `DatetimeIndex` to column, it remove duplcicates by all columns, here `Date` and column `Val`:

```
df4 =  pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index().drop_duplicates()
print (df4)
        Date     Val
0 2020-02-20  152.50
1 2020-02-19  152.53 <-not dupe, different datetime
2 2020-02-18  152.20
3 2020-02-13  152.28 <-dupe
4 2018-02-20  152.53 <-not dupe, different datetime
5 2018-02-21  141.37
```

If need remove duplicates by `DatetimeIndex` only use

```
df5 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df5 = df5[~df5.index.duplicated()]
print (df5)
Date              
2020-02-20  152.50
2020-02-19  152.53
2020-02-18  152.20
2020-02-13  152.28 <-dupe
2018-02-20  152.53
2018-02-21  141.37
```

Or remove duplicates by column `Date` specified in `subset` parameter:

```
df51 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['Date'])
print (df51)
        Date     Val
0 2020-02-20  152.50
1 2020-02-19  152.53
2 2020-02-18  152.20
3 2020-02-13  152.28 <-dupe
4 2018-02-20  152.53
5 2018-02-21  141.37
```

Comment: can you explain why without the reset it remove some of the dates ?

Comment: @yehudahs - If there is `DatetimeIndex` only checked duplicates in `Val` column

Answer (score 0):

Does the `verify_integrity` option of pandas' [concat method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) makes the trick? In your case, it would look like this:

```py
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], verify_integrity=True)
```

Comment: It does not fix duplicated index